# AWS S3 deploy without changing credentials

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

This is not a EC2 instance (just for info)

I built a node.js app and I'm handling requests for images with app.use("/images", s3Proxy({...})). These images are sent to my aws s3 bucket and then served.With multer-s3 I'm  uploading images to my bucket. For these two packages I need to use my credentials to sign in (access_key, secret_access_key and session_token).

The problem is these credentials are only temporary and if I deploy the app, they expire and my app doesn't handle requests for the images no more. What is the solution to this problem?

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");
require("dotenv").config();

const { S3Client } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3");

const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const multer = require("multer");

const cors = require("cors");

const { graphqlHTTP } = require("express-graphql");
const schema = require("./util/schema");
const resolver = require("./util/resolver");
const isAuth = require("./middleware/isAuth");
const s3Proxy = require("s3-proxy");

const app = express();

const s3 = new S3Client({
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    sessionToken: process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
  },
  region: "eu-central-1",
});

app.options("*", cors());
app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: "express-app-recipe",
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, uuidv4());
    },
  }),
});

app.use(
  "/images/",
  s3Proxy({
    bucket: "express-app-recipe",
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    sessionToken: process.env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
  })
);

app.use(isAuth);

app.post("/post-image", upload.single("image"), (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.isAuth) {
    const error = new Error("Not authenticated");
    error.statusCode = 401;
    throw error;
  }

  if (!req.file) {
    const error = new Error("No file attached!");
    error.statusCode = 400;
    throw error;
  }


  return res.status(201).send({
    message: "File recieved",
    filePath: req.file.key,
  });
});

app.use(
  "/graphql",
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    rootValue: resolver,
    graphiql: true,
    customFormatErrorFn(err) {
      if (!err.originalError) {
        return err;
      }
      const data = err.originalError.data; // naš seznam izjem
      const message = err.message || "An error occured";
      const code = err.originalError.code;

      return { message: message, status: code, data: data };
    },
  })
);

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(error);
  const status = error.statusCode;
  const data = error.data;
  const message = error.message;
  res.status(status).json({ message: message, data: data });
});

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DB_CONN)
  .then((result) => {
    app.listen(process.env.PORT);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Renew the credentials if they have expired?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `sts.assumeRole()` to refresh the token dynamically. In `AssumeRole`, you can specify `DurationSeconds` argument to specify the duration of the temporary credentials returned which is returned by STS.

Also, you can proactively refresh the token before it is about to expire.

Please see AWS [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/javascript_sts_code_examples.html) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55099370/find-a-better-way-to-renew-aws-credentials).